# How to recognize when a group of messages has been delivered

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a web application that allows a user to run a large batch of identical tasks. Those tasks are executed by a command pattern that is backed by a message channel in Spring Integration.

I'm looking for a way to logically group the command messages from a single batch together so that a listener can be set that will be able to tell when all the individual messages in that group have been processed.

I'm looking for a mechanism in Spring Integration to do this in the documentation but I'm kind of at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

See [the aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator). You can specify a custom correlation strategy to define the group.

The default correlation strategy uses the `correlationId` header.

You need a release strategy to determine when the group can be released.